# Anaconda and its libraries in macOS Catalina

Tags: catalina, python, gcc

Apple is constantly introducing changes to how it handles a range of issues. Some are, I assume, security-related. This affects programming environments such as **Python (Anaconda)** and **R** and others. Placing moved from */Library/Frameworks/* to */opt/* to *~/opt/*. This really affects productivity. Also, there are libraries such as **intel-openmp** that rely on **gcc** (from [hpc](http://hpc.sourceforge.net)). Things are changing and becoming unbearably messy.

Can anyone compile a sensible how-to's / recommendations:

- Home for Anaconda (*/opt/* or *~/opt/*)?
- How to compile **gcc** that is required by **openmp**?